# How to retrieve validation errors in .NET Core 7 App

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I have an ASP.NET Core 7 MVC controller that returns `IResult`.

If I return, for example, `Results.ValidationProblem(result.Errors)`, where `result.Errors` are a list of the errors that occurred, the client only receives a "Bad Request" HTTP error and the exception shows no actual errors.

How can I get the validation errors? If I set status code as 200 in `Results.ValidationProblem` call, client only received an OK without underlying message.

How can I do that?

Comment: A validation error *is* a bad request, by definition. What's the actual response?  Validation errors are returned automatically in a Bad Request response that contains the actual errors in a form that follows [RFC 7808 - Problem Details for HTTP APIs](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7807).

Comment: Why do you want to return validation errors as OK?

Comment: If the request fails validation, ASP.NET Core itself will return an RFC7807 response without calling the controller action. It's possible to [customize the problem details response](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/handle-errors?view=aspnetcore-7.0#client-error-response) in various ways. An action can also return its own ProblemDetails response with `return Problem(...)`. Check the [Problem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.problem?view=aspnetcore-7.0) method

Comment: can you brief more

Comment: It's also possible to `return ValidationProblem(...)` with the [ValidationProblem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.validationproblem?view=aspnetcore-7.0) method

Comment: I have found this. It seems this was bug bug but it is already fixed, according to this: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/41634, but I cannot see if it really works.